# Smooth bootstrap3 mobile animations

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-transitions

Why bootstrap's animations on mobile devices is so slow?
Even default navbar of bs3 on my Nexus 4 is antsy and buggy.
css3 transformations for GPU accelerating doesnt help.
Here is demo http://m.schedule.sumdu.edu.ua/ (ukrainian)
Using lates Chrome Mobile beta, default navbar at this site is very laggy.

How to improme aniamations on mobile devices?

Comment: What animations are you talking about ? I can't see anything on you page.

Comment: @kursus resize browser window to <=767px and click dropdown toggle